# syntax error at 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, navicat

If I run my query in python, it returns a syntax error.

However, if I run this with navicat, it work's fine.

Why doesn't it run in python?

**sql_query**

```
INSERT INTO
    solarsystem
    (
        solarsystemName,
        solarsystemPositionX,
        solarsystemPositionY,
        solarsystemSectorId,
        solarsystemAngle
    ) 
VALUES 
    ('Lima [698/562]',698,562,13,171);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

**error**

> 1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'

---

**[EDIT]**

**create.py**

```
[...]

args = (solarsytem['solarsystemName'], solarsytem['x_pos'], solarsytem['y_pos'],
        solarsytem['sector_id'], solarsytem['angle'])

with self.engine.begin() as connection:
    result_proxy = connection.execute(sql_query, args).first()

[...]
```

**UPDATE**

If I try the `INSERT` as single query this works.

However, `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` didn't work. It returns:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Help us help you - share your python code too

Comment: Have you tried executing these two statements with two separate `execute` calls?

Comment: Yes, If i run `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM solarsystem ;` it returns _TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting_ ( i run this without args) but in Navicat it always work's

Answer (score 1):

Do it over your connection to get the last row ID inserted on the cursor object,

You can use

```
connection.insert_id()
```

Or if you have a cursor:

```
cursor.lastrowid
```

**EDIT**

For sqlalchemy you can use:

```
with self.engine.begin() as connection:
        result_proxy = connection.execute(sql_query, args).first()
        last_id=result_proxy.inserted_primary_key[0]
```

And you will have your id in `last_id`

But you must remove the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` from your sql_query

Comment: AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'insert_id'

Comment: Use **connection.lastrowid**, it is because you gave your cursor a connection name

Comment: _AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'lastrowid'_

**connection = self.engine.connect()** ist the connector not a cursor. Or did I get this wrong?

Comment: How it works? I make a INSERT and nothing will be returned. That's the next error: _This result object does not return rows_